# Reactivemongo failing on AWS and Google Compute

Tags: playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am running into strange situation, I am using version 11.11 for play 2.5.1. My application is working fine with local mongodb. When I launch applicaiton on AWS or Google compute, it is stuck during collection.find, as a fact any type of operations on collection is stuck. I have installed mongodb local to the instance itself, I am able to connect and add collection to mongodb through shell.

**Same is working totally fine on digital ocean**

Can someone help me what might be going wrong

Configuration

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://"${?MONGO_HOST}":"${?MONGO_PORT}"/service_collection"

mongo-async-driver {
  akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = DEBUG
  }
}
```

Following are from my build and plugins file.

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.11"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.1")
```

Logs
Reactive mongo logs

```
[info] application - ReactiveMongoApi starting...
[info] application - ReactiveMongoApi successfully configured with DB 'service_collection'! Servers:
        [127.0.0.1:27017]
```

On mongodb side these are the following logs, I don't see any query reaching mongodb from logs.

Mongodb logs

```
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.891 [initandlisten] opening db:  local
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.892 [initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile version #)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.892 [initandlisten]     local
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.892 [initandlisten]     service_collection
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.892 [initandlisten] opening db:  service_collection
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] done repairDatabases
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] run command local.$cmd { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true }
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] opening db:  local
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] create collection local.startup_log { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true }
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:75 0ms
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] insert local.startup_log ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0  0ms
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] fd limit hard:64000 soft:64000 max conn: 51200
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 BackgroundJob starting: TTLMonitor
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 BackgroundJob starting: PeriodicTask::Runner
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 BackgroundJob starting: ClientCursorMonitor
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.893 [websvr] fd limit hard:64000 soft:64000 max conn: 51200
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.894 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sat Apr  9 01:20:25.894 BackgroundJob starting: snapshot
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.471 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58316 #1 (1 connection now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.473 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58317 #2 (2 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.473 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58318 #3 (3 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.475 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58319 #4 (4 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.475 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58320 #5 (5 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.475 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58321 #6 (6 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.477 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58322 #7 (7 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.477 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58323 #8 (8 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.477 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58324 #9 (9 connections now open)
Sat Apr  9 01:20:33.477 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58325 #10 (10 connections now open)
```

Comment: To get the log, `<logger name="reactivemongo" value="TRACE"/>` should be added in Play logging.

Comment: When do you call ``collection.find()`` ? Are you sure your db is ready when you're performing this call ?